# Asynchronously get and store images in python

Tags: python, urllib, python-requests

The following code is a sample of non-asynchronous code, is there any way to get the images asynchronously?

```
import urllib
for x in range(0,10):
        urllib.urlretrieve("http://test.com/file %s.png" % (x), "temp/file %s.png" % (x))
```

I have also seen the [Grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) library but I couldn't figure much if that is possible or how to do it from the documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need any third party library. Just create a thread for every request, start the threads, and then wait for all of them to finish in the background, or continue your application while the images are being downloaded.

```
import threading

results = []
def getter(url, dest):
   results.append(urllib.urlretreave(url, dest))

threads = []
for x in range(0,10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=getter, args=('http://test.com/file %s.png' % x,
                                              'temp/file %s.png' % x))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
# wait for all threads to finish
# You can continue doing whatever you want and
# join the threads when you finally need the results.
# They will fatch your urls in the background without
# blocking your main application.
map(lambda t: t.join(), threads)
```

Optionally you can create a thread pool that will get `urls` and `dests` from a queue.

If you're using Python 3 it's already implemented for you in the [`futures`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/concurrent.futures.html) module.

Comment: Superb. I don't know how I was living w/o multithreading so far. Thanks

Comment: Awesomely simple and useful answer! The use of `map` was superb (haven't used it before but I'm learning it now)

Comment: Note that this use of map does not work anymore in python 3 as a map is not being evaluated directly anymore (only when the actual data is needed). You can use `[x.join() for x in threads]` as a one-liner, or write out the two-line for-loop `for x in threads: x.join()`.

Comment: Hi, suppose I have 100k image urls. And i am using thread pooling in python 3.12. Will the program start a 100k threads?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should help you

```
import grequests
urls = ['url1', 'url2', ....] # this should be the list of urls

    requests = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
    responses = grequests.map(requests)
    for response in responses:
        if 199 < response.status_code < 400:
             name = generate_file_name()    # generate some name for your image file with extension like example.jpg
             with open(name, 'wb') as f:    # or save to S3 or something like that
                  f.write(response.content)
```

Here only the downloading of images would be parallel but writing each image content to a file would be sequential so you can create a thread or do something else to make it parallel or asynchronous