# How to parallelize file downloads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, subprocess, wget

I can download a file at a time with:

```
import urllib.request

urls = ['foo.com/bar.gz', 'foobar.com/barfoo.gz', 'bar.com/foo.gz']

for u in urls:
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(u)
```

I could try to `subprocess` it as such:

```
import subprocess
import os

def parallelized_commandline(command, files, max_processes=2):
    processes = set()
    for name in files:
        processes.add(subprocess.Popen([command, name]))
        if len(processes) >= max_processes:
            os.wait()
            processes.difference_update(
                [p for p in processes if p.poll() is not None])

    #Check if all the child processes were closed
    for p in processes:
        if p.poll() is None:
            p.wait()

urls = ['http://www.statmt.org/wmt15/training-monolingual-nc-v10/news-commentary-v10.en.gz',
'http://www.statmt.org/wmt15/training-monolingual-nc-v10/news-commentary-v10.cs.gz', 
'http://www.statmt.org/wmt15/training-monolingual-nc-v10/news-commentary-v10.de.gz']

parallelized_commandline('wget', urls)
```

Is there any way to parallelize `urlretrieve` without using `os.system` or `subprocess` to cheat?

Given that I must resort to the "cheat" for now, is `subprocess.Popen` the right way to download the data?

When using the `parallelized_commandline()` above, it's using multi-thread but not multi-core for the `wget`, is that normal? Is there a way to make it multi-core instead of multi-thread?

Comment: the other thing you could look at is threads, i know it can slow down some tasks, but for IO bound tasks it usually results in a speedup as it switches to other threads when the IO starts to block, I'm not sure if it would help in this case, but you could give it a go

Comment: or *cheat* by launching each in `screen` ... if you don't need to sync on them being done.  `subprocess.call(['screen','-S','sleepx','-dm','sleep','876543210'])`

Comment: Pls take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377475/asynchronously-get-and-store-images-in-python

Comment: related: [How to download a few files simultaneusly from ftp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16140921/4279)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could use a thread pool to download files in parallel:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads for I/O bound tasks
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

urls = [...]
result = Pool(4).map(urlretrieve, urls) # download 4 files at a time
```

You could also download several files at once in a single thread using `asyncio`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import logging
from contextlib import closing
import aiohttp # $ pip install aiohttp

@asyncio.coroutine
def download(url, session, semaphore, chunk_size=1<<15):
    with (yield from semaphore): # limit number of concurrent downloads
        filename = url2filename(url)
        logging.info('downloading %s', filename)
        response = yield from session.get(url)
        with closing(response), open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            while True: # save file
                chunk = yield from response.content.read(chunk_size)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                file.write(chunk)
        logging.info('done %s', filename)
    return filename, (response.status, tuple(response.headers.items()))

urls = [...]
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
with closing(asyncio.get_event_loop()) as loop, \
     closing(aiohttp.ClientSession()) as session:
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(4)
    download_tasks = (download(url, session, semaphore) for url in urls)
    result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*download_tasks))
```

where [`url2filename()` is defined here](https://gist.github.com/zed/c2168b9c52b032b5fb7d).

Comment: How to download images to specific directory?

Comment: @neel do you see filename in the code? Replace it with `os.path.join(destination_directory, filename)`. If it is unclear; ask a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear, I was asking in the Pool.

Comment: @neel define your own `fetch_url()`, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27986480/4279) and pass it to the pool instead of `urlretrieve()`.  You could use `urlretrieve(url, os.path.join(destination_directory, filename))` inside your fetch_url() function.

Comment: Similarly how to upload files block by block in parallel using python ?

Comment: @AshishKarpe if you haven't found an existing question about it, ask a new Stack Overflow question (this question is about downloading)

Comment: @jfs Hi, how can I get data (binary I think?) in list of result? Because result is list, and inside list is tuple. Inside the tupple I cannot get the file data (binary or base64 or something like that)

Comment: *Edit: nvm, now i got it :)
The file just saved in folder where is script running

Comment: Is it possible to download using asyncio and wget. I tried the above answer but downloads are incomplete for many urls. It could be the source site issue but when I tried looping using wget, I got complete files.