# File download with concurrent.futures or multiprocessing - How to stop on Ctrl-C?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpoolexecutor

I've read a lot of questions on SO and elsewhere on this topic but can't get it working. Perhaps it's because I'm using Windows, I don't know.

What I'm trying to do is download a bunch of files (whose URLs are read from a CSV file) in parallel. I've tried using `multiprocessing` and `concurrent.futures` for this with no success.

The main problem is that I can't stop the program on Ctrl-C - it just keeps running. This is especially bad in the case of processes instead of threads (I used `multiprocessing` for that) because I have to kill each process manually every time.

Here is my current code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import signal
import sys
import urllib.request

class Download(object):
  def __init__(self, url, filename):
    self.url = url
    self.filename = filename

def perform_download(download):
  print('Downloading {} to {}'.format(download.url, download.filename))
  return urllib.request.urlretrieve(download.url, filename=download.filename)  

def main(argv):
  args = parse_args(argv)
  queue = []
  with open(args.results_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as results_file:
    # Irrelevant CSV parsing...
    queue.append(Download(url, filename))

  def handle_interrupt():
    print('CAUGHT SIGINT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!11111111')
    sys.exit(1)

  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_interrupt)

  with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=args.num_jobs) as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(perform_download, d): d for d in queue}
    try:
      concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print('Interrupted')
      sys.exit(1)
```

I'm trying to catch Ctrl-C in two different ways here but none of them works. The latter one (`except KeyboardInterrupt`) actually gets run but the process won't exit after calling `sys.exit`.

Before this I used the `multiprocessing` module like this:

```
try:      
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=args.num_jobs)
    pool.map_async(perform_download, queue).get(1000000)
  except Exception as e:
    pool.close()
    pool.terminate()
    sys.exit(0)
```

So what is the proper way to add ability to terminate all worker threads or processes once you hit Ctrl-C in the terminal?

System information:

- Python version: 3.6.1 32-bit
- OS: Windows 10

Comment: At least for the multiprocessing module, it is a known bug:
http://bugs.python.org/issue8296
Also see 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408356/keyboard-interrupts-with-pythons-multiprocessing-pool

Comment: this one worked for me.try https://stackoverflow.com/a/31795242/4385319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are catching the `SIGINT` signal in a signal handler and re-routing it as a `SystemExit` exception. This prevents the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception to ever reach your main loop.

Moreover, if the `SystemExit` is not raised in the main thread, it will just kill the child thread where it is raised.

Jesse Noller, the author of the `multiprocessing` library, explains how to deal with `CTRL+C` in a old [blog post](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/01/08/multiprocessingpool-and-keyboardinterrupt).

```
import signal
from multiprocessing import Pool


def initializer():
    """Ignore CTRL+C in the worker process."""
    signal.signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)


pool = Pool(initializer=initializer)

try:
    pool.map(perform_download, dowloads)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the accepted answer works under Windows, certainly not under current versions of Python (I am running 3.8.5). In fact, it won't run at all since `SIGINT` and `SIG_IGN` will be undefined (what is needed is `signal.SIGINT` and `signal.SIG_IGN`).

This is a know problem under Windows. A solution I have come up with is essentially the reverse of the accepted solution: The main process must ignore keyboard interrupts and we initialize the process pool to *initially* set a global flag `ctrl_c_entered` to `False` and to set this flag to `True` if Ctrl-C is entered. Then any multiprocessing worker function (or method) is decorated with a special decorator, `handle_ctrl_c`, that firsts tests the `ctrl_c_entered` flag and only if `False` does it run the worker function after re-enabling keyboard interrupts and establishing a try/catch handler for keyboard interrups. If the `ctrl_c_entered` flag was `True` or if a keyboard interrupt occurs during the execution of the worker function, the value returned is an instance of `KeyboardInterrupt`, which the main process can check to determine whether a Ctrl-C was entered.

Thus all submitted tasks will be allowed to start but will immediately terminate with a return value of a KeyBoardInterrupt exception and the actual worker function will never be called by the decorator function once a Ctrl-C has been entered.

```py
import signal
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import wraps
import time

def handle_ctrl_c(func):
    """
    Decorator function.
    """
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global ctrl_c_entered
        if not ctrl_c_entered:
            # re-enable keyboard interrups:
            signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, default_sigint_handler)
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                ctrl_c_entered = True
                return KeyboardInterrupt()
            finally:
                signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, pool_ctrl_c_handler)
        else:
            return KeyboardInterrupt()
    return wrapper

def pool_ctrl_c_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    global ctrl_c_entered
    ctrl_c_entered = True

def init_pool():
    # set global variable for each process in the pool:
    global ctrl_c_entered
    global default_sigint_handler
    ctrl_c_entered = False
    default_sigint_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, pool_ctrl_c_handler)

@handle_ctrl_c
def perform_download(download):
    print('begin')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('end')
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    pool = Pool(initializer=init_pool)
    results = pool.map(perform_download, range(20))
    if any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, KeyboardInterrupt), results)):
        print('Ctrl-C was entered.')
    print(results)
```